# Kafka entries to DynamoDB

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-dynamodb, kafka-consumer-api, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I want all records coming in Kafka topic to be inserted in DynamoDB. Is there any open source plugin available which can do the same.  Or is there any other better way that I can do it within DynamoDB itself.

Pls Suggest

Lokesh Narayan

Answer (score 1):

Storing Kafka messages in DynamoDB is a great use case for Kafka Connect. Unfortunately I don't know of any off-the-shelf sink connectors for DynamoDB. You can see a list [here](http://www.confluent.io/product/connectors). For now, you'll need to either build your own sink connector (and hopefully open source it!) or build a custom consumer that writes to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

However, I found this [kafka-connect-dynamodb](https://github.com/shikhar/kafka-connect-dynamodb). Though it is currently unmaintained, it worked for me.